# Django view gets unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django

I tried get the id from my database and make something like `/article/1/`. `1` is the id of my article but it didn't work.

views.py

```
def article(request, article_id):
    return render_to_response('article.html', {{'article': Articles.objects.get(id=article_id)}})
```

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('showall/', views.articles, name='articles'),
    path('<int:article_id>/', views.articles, name='article'),

]
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError at /article/1/ articles() got an unexpected keyword argument 'article_id'
```

I also include image of my datebase

[Datebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbdJR.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you are using `views.articles` for the article detail view:

```
path('<int:article_id>/', views.articles, name='article'),
```

You should use `views.article` instead:

```
path('<int:article_id>/', views.article, name='article'),
```

Note that there are a few improvements/fixes you can make to your `article` view:

- Use `get_object_or_404` so that you don't get a server error when the article does not exist in the database
- Use `render` instead of the obsolete `render_to_response`
- The context dictionary should be a dictionary `{...}`. You currently have double curly brackets `{{...}}`

Putting that together you get:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def article(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)
    return render(request, 'article.html', {'article': article})
```

Comment: thx it work with    return render_to_response('article.html', {'article': article})

Comment: I've fixed the example using `render` now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `views.py` defines an `article` function while your `urls.py` makes use of an `articles` (note the plural) function. Is this a typo, or is there any `articles` function in `views.py` that does **not** support an optional `article_id` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You are using views.articles in *article/id/* url which most likely you have used for *article/showAll/* url. Use this instead:

```
path('<int:article_id>/', views.article, name='article')
```